# Mule multiple Batch processing

Tags: mule

My flows are invoking multiple batch process. I want to process the batch in sequential i.e

> Batch-1->Batch-2->Batch-3->...

```
<quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="Fetch" repeatInterval="0" repeatCount="0" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz" startDelay="5000">
    <quartz:event-generator-job/>
</quartz:inbound-endpoint>
<scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather">
    <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
        <batch:execute name="Batch-1" doc:name="Batch-1"/>
        <logger message="==Batch-1 END==" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <batch:execute name="Batch-2" doc:name="Batch-2"/>
     </processor-chain>
</scatter-gather>
```

Here, it goes to Batch-1, enters input state of batch-1, after end of input phase, thread comes to Batch-2 then input phase of Batch-2. It doesn't wait for Batch-1 different STEPS of each batch to complete and process the Batch-2. How do I handle this?
I tried with two process chain each batch in process chains separately, it didn't work out. Without scatter gather I am facing same issue.

Batch flows:

```
<batch:job name="Batch-1">
    <batch:input>
        <logger message="==Invoke query====" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </batch:input>
    <batch:process-records>
        <batch:step name="Batch_Step">                
            <flow-ref name="sfdc-query" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:process-records>
    <batch:on-complete>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="On Complete:#[message.payload]"/>           
    </batch:on-complete>
</batch:job>
```

> EDIT

Now, I have 5 process, A,B,C,D,E. It should process first A then next process is all of(B,C,D) in parallel. Once after B and D finishes, finally E should process. C can process parallel with B & D. How do map this?

Comment: Scatter-gather will make your process parallel .. so, if you are having the issue then you can call these 2 batch process sequentially .. or you can also follow what star has mentioned in his solution to call the batch2 after batch1 completes

Comment: @AnirbanSenChowdhary, other than Star mentioned below, how Do I call batch sequentially? Edited question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Batch-1 `Oncomplete Phase`, use  VM call the second flow( Create new flow), in the second flow use batch Execute to call Batch-2.

Comment: it worked!. edit question above for another scenario.

Comment: In the same way.  In batch-1(A), on complete phase call the next flow via VM, where in next flow use scatter-gather ( if you need to process it parallel,  call  3 batch execute(B,C,D). When scatter-Gather finished processing. Call final batch execute E. I haven't used these many batch scope all at a time. Please test for memory issue also.

Comment: problem is from where should I call batch-E since it has to be invoked after B and D completes. I have configured in this way: Process Batch-A, on complete, do scatter-gather(parallel) for C and B. On complete of Batch-B, invoke Batch-D which invokes Batch-E at the end. A-->(C,[B-->D-->E])

Comment: ok, try this. Batch-A, on complete( VM call 2nd flow), second flow :VM-flowref(3rd flow)-batchExecute(call D).  3rd flow have scatter gather alone ( means C and B). Finally D( final  flow), on complete call E. If this is not working. Use your way.